# doctrine mapping not found case

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, mapping

I have a table A which references table B.

edit: Database engine used is MyISAM.

Doctrine mapping works like a charm, except when I have non valid case in the DB where referenced ID in table A does not really exist in table B.

So when you execute this code:

```
$objectB = $objectA->getObjectB();//with lazy load
```

you actually get $objectB proxy object which is ***not null***. So !empty($objectB) will pass.

And when you try to access any property of $objectB, like:

> $objectB->getName();

you get *Entity not found exception*. There is not way you can predict in your code that $objectB actually does **not exist** and that there's no Name property for $objectB.

$objectB should actually be set to null but that is not happening.

Hibernate has actually mapping property *not-found=ignore* which sets missing object to **NULL** instead of setting it to Proxy object. Does Doctrine has anything similar?

PS. Of course you can always catch the Entity not found exception, and play around with that. Or you can map the actual objectB_ID field at the table A, but those are not 100% clean solutions.

I hope someone has an answer.

Thank You

Comment: If you expect an object from a getter and it returns null, maybe you should test for null first. It's a little more complex because Doctrine creates proxy objects for you, but the principle is the same.

Comment: That is exactly my question. How do you test for NULL a proxy object that does not have physical record in the DB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> except when I have non valid case in the DB where referenced ID in table A does not really exist in table B

IMO this is a case of garbage in, garbage out. If you have schema where TableA may or may not have a row in TableB, you should implement a FK constraint on TableB, so that if a row is deleted from TableB, any rows in TableA referencing deleted rows will have their values changed to null.

If you really wanted to move forward on your proposed schema implementation, you could try doing:

```
$rowExists = ($objectA->getObjectB()->getId() > 0) ? true : false;
```

This of course assumes you have an id column on tableB and that it is unsigned.

**-- Update --**

```
try {
    $objectB = $objectA->getObjectB();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $objectB = null;
}

if ($objectB instanceof ClassB) {
    // Do work
}
```

Comment: If you run this: $objectA->getObjectB()->getId() > 0 ? true : false; you would get _Entity not found_ exception thrown.

Comment: One other thing. Database engine used is MyISAM so FK constraint is no solution in this case. Yes, there is a lot of garbage in the database. But I'm looking for Doctrine solution for this situation.

Comment: Yes. I get Entity not found exception.

Comment: Updated solution with a try/catch block, it should work for your situation.

Comment: It's a late reply, but try/catch is the way to go for this problem.

Comment: This solution also works with soft-deletable Entities, which is a typical use-case provoking such types of problems. So from the database perspective the relation is OK, but Doctrine won't fetch a soft-deleted related Entity and throws a `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException`.

Comment: If doctrine is going to force you to force normal program flow through exception handling then avoid it. Use raw queries instead with setter method to simply set your entity in memory. I'd post an answer but this post is old, these answers will get you there and Doctrine has proven to be a complete waste of my time. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at one of your generated proxy classes, you'll see that the `__load()` and `__clone()` functions both throw the `EntityNotFoundException`.

The `__load()` function is called when you "lazily" call the `getName()` function.

```
class ObjectB extends \Foo\Entity\ObjectB implements \Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy
{
    private $_entityPersister;
    private $_identifier;
    public $__isInitialized__ = false;
    public function __construct($entityPersister, $identifier)
    {
        $this->_entityPersister = $entityPersister;
        $this->_identifier = $identifier;
    }
    /** @private */
    public function __load()
    {
        if (!$this->__isInitialized__ && $this->_entityPersister) {
            $this->__isInitialized__ = true;

            if (method_exists($this, "__wakeup")) {
                // call this after __isInitialized__to avoid infinite recursion
                // but before loading to emulate what ClassMetadata::newInstance()
                // provides.
                $this->__wakeup();
            }

            if ($this->_entityPersister->load($this->_identifier, $this) === null) {
                throw new \Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException();
            }
            unset($this->_entityPersister, $this->_identifier);
        }
    }
...
    public function getName()
    {
        $this->__load();
        return parent::getName();
    }
...
}
```

You basically have a couple of options, the first being use a `try/catch` block.

```
try {
    $name = $objectB->getName();
} catch (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException $e) {
    $name = null;
}
```

Or you can take a look at implementing the [`__wakeup()`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html#safely-implementing-wakeup) function in `ObjectB` and possibly handling this yourself (though you'll more than likely need to throw an exception anyways).

Lastly, if you are feeling ambitious, you can change the `Proxy` template. `\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory` contains the template.

```
    /** Proxy class code template */
    private static $_proxyClassTemplate =
'<?php

namespace <namespace>;

/**
 * THIS CLASS WAS GENERATED BY THE DOCTRINE ORM. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
 */
class <proxyClassName> extends \<className> implements \Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy
{
    private $_entityPersister;
    private $_identifier;
    public $__isInitialized__ = false;
    public function __construct($entityPersister, $identifier)
    {
        $this->_entityPersister = $entityPersister;
        $this->_identifier = $identifier;
    }
    /** @private */
    public function __load()
    {
        if (!$this->__isInitialized__ && $this->_entityPersister) {
            $this->__isInitialized__ = true;

            if (method_exists($this, "__wakeup")) {
                // call this after __isInitialized__to avoid infinite recursion
                // but before loading to emulate what ClassMetadata::newInstance()
            // provides.
                $this->__wakeup();
            }

            if ($this->_entityPersister->load($this->_identifier, $this) === null) {
                throw new \Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException();
            }
            unset($this->_entityPersister, $this->_identifier);
        }
    }
```

You should be able to get away with just removing the throwing of the `EntityNotFoundException` in the `__load()` and `__clone()` functions, though there might be unintended side effects. You'll also probably want to look at doing this change as a patch if you plan on upgrading Doctrine periodically.

Comment: We have old data from legacy app which is very inconsistent. Its very difficult to clean up data manually. I am getting EntityNotFoundException if I load data in table with foreign key check disabled. Is there any way to handle this exception and set the foreign key column value to NULL and rethrow the same exception if doctrine couldn't find related entity so that data will automatically be cleanedup ?

Answer (score 1):

Use it in your annotation in ObjectA class:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ObjectB", fetch="EAGER")
```

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue using Doctrine ORM where Object A was important enough that we didn't want to simply delete it using some sort of cleanup script if Object A no longer existed. This would not occur during the normal application execution but very rarely when manually editing database tables, such as during migrations/upgrades.

A couple of options we considered but weren't too keen on:

- Using vendor specific fixes, in this case an `ON DELETE SET NULL` constraint for [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186712.aspx)).
- Using a custom Twig extension to catch the EntityNotFoundException (we were only really experiencing this issue in Twig templates but didn't want to have to add the extension everywhere, and then still potentially have problems within our PHP controllers).

Instead, we decided to pollute our entities a little bit by catching the EntityNotFoundException within them but to contain all logic to an EntityExistanceCheckableTrait trait.

Once the trait is added to both Object A and Object B, then all we needed to do was call `$objectB->hasObjectB()` or `{{ objectB.hasObjectA() }}` in Twig and handle this as dictated by the logic of the controller/template.

```
class ObjectA
{
    use EntityExistanceCheckableTrait;

    ...
}
```

and

```
class ObjectB
{
    use EntityExistanceCheckableTrait;

    ...

    public function hasObjectB()
    {
        return $this->hasEntity('ObjectB');
    }
}
```

The trait adds the __invoke() PHP magic method that simply returns true if it exists but this is all we need to make the proxy load and see if the associated entity actually eixsts or is just an orphan ID in the associated entity.

Here is the full code of the trait:

```
/**
 * Add to the entities on both sides of a Doctrine Association then implement a wrapper around hasEntity() in the
 * owning entity.
 *
 * Trait EntityExistanceCheckableTrait
 */
trait EntityExistanceCheckableTrait
{
    /**
     * This can be empty but needs to be defined so we can check that the entity is callable.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $entityName
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasEntity($entityName)
    {
        // Create the callable method
        $entityMethod = 'get'.$entityName;

        try {
            $entity = $this->$entityMethod();

            // We invoke the associated entity to force the real entity to be lazy-loaded instead of the proxy.
            // This way we can ensure that we don't have an orphan entity (e.g. a proxy with the ID of the associated
            // entity, loaded from the original entity, but the associated entity no longer exists in the database).
            return (isset($entity) && $entity()) ? true : false;
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```